# Как сделать, чтобы в одном фрагменте каждый раз открывался новый класс?

Tags: android-fragment, android

Как сделать, что бы в одном фрагменте открывался новый класс?

Вот у меня лайаут:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="134dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.testing.MyFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Здесь прописано, что бы сразу открывался нужный класс, а как сделать, что бы по клику на листвью, открывался соотвествующий класс в этом фрагменте? Можно так сделать?

Comment: Если я правильно поняла, во фрагмент name не обязательно сразу прописывать. Можно помещать классы во фрагмент по id. Но как то этот вариант отказывается работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не обязательно делать так, как вы описали, воспользуйтесь вот этим способом

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(oldFragmentId, newFragment).commit();
```